# How to put this imageView in this place? - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I've got a problem with adding logo to my app.

Now it's like:

[HERE IS A LOGO - CLICK (haven't got 10 reputation)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1Hev.png)

I want to have a imageview with logo (id: logo) above the box with login.
How to make it?

**Layout.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:fb="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/log"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">




    <ScrollView
        android:background="@drawable/log"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:background="@drawable/login"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"


            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="120dp">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/napis"
                android:id="@+id/logosek" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/social_signin_layout"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@color/md_white_1000"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_or"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:text="@string/screen_login_or_label"
                    android:textColor="@color/md_black_1000"
                    android:textSize="24sp" />

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/material_color_primary"
                    app:hintAnimationEnabled="true"
                    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/et_usernamelogin"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/screen_register_hint_email"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                <!--<EditText-->
                <!--android:id="@+id/"-->
                <!--style="@style/edittextstyle"-->
                <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="@dimen/editlayimg_edittextheight"-->
                <!--android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/five"-->
                <!--android:gravity="bottom"-->
                <!--android:hint="@string/login_storeid"-->
                <!--android:singleLine="true"-->
                <!--android:textColorHint="@color/fontcolorlight"-->
                <!--android:textSize="18sp" />-->

                <!--<View-->
                <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="@dimen/one"-->
                <!--android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/five"-->
                <!--android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/five"-->
                <!--android:background="@color/fontcolorlight" />-->

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/material_color_primary"
                    app:hintAnimationEnabled="true"
                    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/et_passwordlogin"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Password"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_login"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/btnheight"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:background="@color/material_color_accent"
                    android:text="@string/screen_login_button_login"
                    android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/btnlogin_textsize" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txt_signup"

                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                        android:text="@string/screen_login_button_sign_up"
                        android:textColor="@color/md_black_1000"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_forgotpwd"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:paddingRight="8dp"
                        android:text="Forgot Password?"
                        android:textColor="@color/md_black_1000"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lay_above"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/md_brown_100"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/social_signin_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/lay_above"
>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:text="Choose account to login"

                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textColor="@color/md_yellow_50"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="17sp" />

                <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
                    android:id="@+id/btn_sign_in"
                    android:layout_width="300dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:padding="0dp"
                    android:theme="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
                    app:theme="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:text="or"

                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textColor="@color/AntiqueWhite"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:id="@+id/textView10" />

                <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
                    android:id="@+id/authButton"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"

                    android:layout_width="300dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:text="@string/please_login_in"

                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textColor="@color/md_yellow_50"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:id="@+id/textView12" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:text="Welcome, Saiyan!"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
                android:id="@+id/textView14"
                android:textSize="36sp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/lay_above"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:textColor="@color/Yellow" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If you can reduce your code to the minimum necessary to reproduce your problem, you chances of getting a reply would increase.

Answer (score 0):

just put the imageview before the relative layout

instead of:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:background="@drawable/login"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"


        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/napis"
            android:id="@+id/logosek" />
```

do:

```
<ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/napis"
            android:id="@+id/logosek" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:background="@drawable/login"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp">
```

this will put imageview in the scrollview and below it the rest of the relativelayout , all because of the linearlayout orientation which directed vertical  , so every child will come below the former.

EDIT : 
you also need to put the scrollview first and then put the linearlayout , this should be it :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:fb="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:background="@drawable/log"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
<LinearLayout 

android:id="@+id/mainView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:background="@drawable/log"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">





    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/napis"
        android:id="@+id/logosek" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:background="@drawable/login"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"


        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/social_signin_layout"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_or"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:text="@string/screen_login_or_label"
                android:textColor="@color/md_black_1000"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                android:textColorHint="@color/material_color_primary"
                app:hintAnimationEnabled="true"

app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_usernamelogin"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/screen_register_hint_email"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <!--<EditText-->
            <!--android:id="@+id/"-->
            <!--style="@style/edittextstyle"-->
            <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="@dimen/editlayimg_edittextheight"-->
            <!--android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/five"-->
            <!--android:gravity="bottom"-->
            <!--android:hint="@string/login_storeid"-->
            <!--android:singleLine="true"-->
            <!--android:textColorHint="@color/fontcolorlight"-->
            <!--android:textSize="18sp" />-->

            <!--<View-->
            <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="@dimen/one"-->
            <!--android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/five"-->
            <!--android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/five"-->
            <!--android:background="@color/fontcolorlight" />-->

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                android:textColorHint="@color/material_color_primary"
                app:hintAnimationEnabled="true"

app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_passwordlogin"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Password"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_login"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/btnheight"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:background="@color/material_color_accent"
                android:text="@string/screen_login_button_login"
                android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
                android:textSize="@dimen/btnlogin_textsize" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_signup"

                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                    android:text="@string/screen_login_button_sign_up"
                    android:textColor="@color/md_black_1000"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_forgotpwd"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:paddingRight="8dp"
                    android:text="Forgot Password?"
                    android:textColor="@color/md_black_1000"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lay_above"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/md_brown_100"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/social_signin_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lay_above"
            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:text="Choose account to login"

                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textColor="@color/md_yellow_50"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="17sp" />

            <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_sign_in"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:theme="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
                app:theme="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:text="or"

                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textColor="@color/AntiqueWhite"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:id="@+id/textView10" />

            <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
                android:id="@+id/authButton"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"

                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:text="@string/please_login_in"

                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textColor="@color/md_yellow_50"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:id="@+id/textView12" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:text="Welcome, Saiyan!"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
            android:id="@+id/textView14"
            android:textSize="36sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lay_above"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textColor="@color/Yellow" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: @BossGuacamole This question is confusing. Do you wanna move the ImageView with id `logosek` above login box, or do you want to add new ImageView with id:logo?